# Remove permissions from a windows folder

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

I have a widows folder on a remote server from which I wish to remove permissions for a specific user.  I've tried numerous methods and nothing seems to work.

I get no errors with the following code but the permission remains intact. Am I not using the correct objects or missing some step with these objects?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The dirName is passed as a share, e.g. \myserver\myfolder

```
private void removePermissions(string dirName, string username)
    {
        string user = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + username;
        DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);
        DirectorySecurity dsec = dirinfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);

        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = dsec.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
        foreach (AccessRule rule in rules)
        {
            if (rule.IdentityReference.Value == user)
            {
                bool value;
                dsec.PurgeAccessRules(rule.IdentityReference);
                dsec.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.RemoveAll, rule, out value);
                MessageBox.Show("Removed permission from " + dirName + " for " + user);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you executing your application with elevated (run as administrator) rights?

Comment: Yes - I'm a Domain Administrator for execution.  I can add as many permissions as I want via code but can't remove any via code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have created the new ACL you need to apply it to the folder.

Add

```
dirinfo.SetAccessControl(dsec);
```

after the loop.

Comment: Oops, previous comment was spoken too soon.  This does the trick perfectly.  Thanks Richard.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: in British/International English, the phrase "the trick" does not imply deceit or impropriety in the way I gather it would in American English.  "That does the trick" is a common expression meaning simply "that works".